# How to know time for which a thread has been in its current state from traces.txt

Tags: android, android-activity, android-anr-dialog

For example, if I have `traces.txt file` and a thread's state is given as below:

```
"callActivityManagerForStrictModeDropbox" prio=5 tid=71 Suspended
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x13394a00 self=0x42746c00
| sysTid=1659 nice=10 cgrp=bg_non_interactive sched=0/0 handle=0x7b491e80
| state=S schedstat=( 264773038 522311652 63568 ) utm=0 stm=26 core=1 HZ=100
| stack=0x7d40c000-0x7d40e000 stackSize=1036KB
```

From above data, Is there any way to know for how much duration thread has remained in suspended state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no state-change timestamp.  You can't tell how long a thread has been in its current state.

The schedstat and utm/stm can be compared between two consecutive stack traces to see if the thread has executed in the mean time, but that doesn't really help with an ANR.

In Dalvik, a thread in SUSPENDED state in the ANR output would have been in the RUNNING state before the ANR handler woke up -- it was suspended for the purpose of gathering stack traces for the ANR report.  Your trace appears to be from ART, which I can't speak to, but I wouldn't be surprised if it behaved in a similar fashion, in which case your question is easy to answer ("not very long").

Comment: this print is from a bugreport, not ANR trace. But, i am not sure if thread are suspended for caturing stack trace for bugreport also.

Comment: The same mechanism is used. Grabbing a stack trace from a running thread can produce less-than-useful results.